# Struggling with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Im new to AngularJS but I am struggling with getting data in an array to come out via the scope into the view. I have an array and I am trying to get each specific item to come out such as 'Costs Summary By Job Type'

Any help would be much appreciated

Here is the Angular:

```
 $scope.lynchMenu = [
  { MenuFunction: 'Interact', MenuText: 'Job Status YTD Summary',                   MenuObject: 'JobStatusYTDSummary',                  MenuType: 'Report', MenuActive: 1, MenuOrder: 1 },
  { MenuFunction: 'Interact', MenuText: 'Costs Summary By Customer',                MenuObject: 'CostsSummaryByCustomer',               MenuType: 'Report', MenuActive: 1, MenuOrder: 2 },
  { MenuFunction: 'Interact', MenuText: 'Costs Summary By Job Type',                MenuObject: 'CostsSummaryByJobType',                MenuType: 'Report', MenuActive: 1, MenuOrder: 3 },
  { MenuFunction: 'Interact', MenuText: 'Costs Summary By Management Company',      MenuObject: 'CostsSummaryByManagementCompany',      MenuType: 'Report', MenuActive: 1, MenuOrder: 4 },
  { MenuFunction: 'Interact', MenuText: 'WIP Summary By Management Company',        MenuObject: 'WIPSummaryByManagementCompany',        MenuType: 'Report', MenuActive: 1, MenuOrder: 5 },
  { MenuFunction: 'Interact', MenuText: 'WIP Detail By Management Company',         MenuObject: 'WIPDetailByManagementCompany',         MenuType: 'Report', MenuActive: 1, MenuOrder: 6 },
  { MenuFunction: 'Interact', MenuText: 'Incomplete Jobs By Management Company',    MenuObject: 'IncompleteJobsByManagementCompany',    MenuType: 'Report', MenuActive: 1, MenuOrder: 7 },

]; //LynchMenu Layout
```

Here is the HTML

```
 <div class="panel-body">
            <ul class="list-unstyled"> 
            <li ng-repeat="MenuObject in lynchMenu">  
                    {{MenuObject}} <!--Data-binding expression -->
                </li><!--List-->      
            </ul><!--Unordered List-->
        </div><!--Panel Body-->
```

Comment: {{MenuObject.MenuText}}

Comment: I suppose there is a ng-controller directive?

Comment: @pbrownlee88 For learning AngularJS, you must know JavaScript, HTML, and how to deal with the DOM.

Comment: you probably should post a better title next time explaining what you're struggling with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the property name. Try..

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/zym4mBEiXK5ZV0SC3S5U?p=preview)

```
<div class="panel-body">
            <ul class="list-unstyled"> 
            <li ng-repeat="MenuObject in lynchMenu">  

                    {{MenuObject.MenuText}} <!--Data-binding expression -->

                </li><!--List-->      
            </ul><!--Unordered List-->
        </div><!--Panel Body-->
```

Comment: Glad to help. Could you please mark it as the accepted answer if you feel that it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the property with object that you want to show on html

```
<div class="panel-body">
            <ul class="list-unstyled"> 
            <li ng-repeat="MenuObject in lynchMenu">  
                    {{MenuObject.MenuText}} {{MenuObject.MenuType}} {{MenuObject.MenuActive}} <!--Data-binding expression -->
                </li><!--List-->      
            </ul><!--Unordered List-->
        </div><!--Panel Body-->
```

For filteration ng-repeat you can use filter of angularjs